# See trace() of Flash when running in browser

Tags: flash, actionscript, debugging, trace, browser-plugin

What's an easy way to see the `trace()` output of Flash/Flex movies when running in any browser?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Download and install the [content debugger version of Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html).

Enable trace logging ([official guide](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/403/kb403009.html)) by adding an mm.cfg file:

```
ErrorReportingEnable=1

    TraceOutputFileEnable=1
```

Where to save mm.cfg depends on the OS:

- Mac OS X: `/Library/Application Support/Macromedia`
- Windows: `%HOMEDRIVE%\%HOMEPATH%`
- Linux: `/home/user name`

The log file, flashlog.txt, can be found at:

- Windows 95/98/ME/2000/XP: `C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player\Logs`
- Windows Vista: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\Logs`
- Mac OS X: `/Users/username/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/Logs/`
- Linux: `/home/username/.macromedia/Flash_Player/Logs/`

Optionally, you can install the Firefox add-on [FBTracer](http://blog.sephiroth.it/firefox-extensions/flash-tracer-for-firebug/) which displays the trace output in a [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) panel.

Comment: This answer needs updating - the "official steps" link is dead, and FlashTracer hasn't been updated since July 2008.

Comment: It doesn't look like FlashTracer plugin has been updated for the latest version of Firefox.  However I did find a handy standalone GUI at http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/

Comment: You can just open the flashlog.txt; there's no need for a separate plugin to read it.

Comment: Another possible alternative to FlashTracer is FlashFirebug. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashfirebug/

Though I couldn't get it to work (might be a licensing issue), so ended up using Vizzy mentioned above. Also ran across this post on how to get Vizzy working in Chrome: http://www.burnedouthippy.com/2011/02/google-chrome-flash-debugger-and-tracing-in-the-browser/

Comment: Or simply use `import flash.external.*; /*....*/ ExternalInterface.call('console.log', 'this was very tricky');` along with trace?

Comment: It's good that you updated the "official steps" link, but you should also describe those steps here, in case the link goes offline again. StackOverflow guidelines also encourage this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . You don't have to quote the entire page, just the relevant info (how to enable trace logging)

Answer (score 16):

i just use the console.log function (most recent browsers implement it);

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

public static function log(msg:String, caller:Object = null):void{
        var str:String = "";
        if(caller){
            str = getQualifiedClassName(caller);
            str += ":: ";
        }
        str += msg;
        trace(str);
        if(ExternalInterface.available){
            ExternalInterface.call("console.log", str);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You also need to `import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;`.

Answer (score 13):

Check out De Monster's MonsterDebugger. You can debug track objects, traces, and display chains in a lovely AIR application. Very fun to use. And it's open source!

http://demonsterdebugger.com/

You can also configure Flash and Flex to write to a log file. Check out how to do that here:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=logging_04.html

I've been using Monster lately, but I used to have an alias that ran a unix "tail" on the flashlog file that would effectively give me a logging window for "in browser" tracing:

```
alias flashlog='tail -f /PATH/TO/flashlog.txt'
```

Or if you have a log viewer (like Console on Mac OS), you can view the log there. The only reason I suggest these options is that FlashTracer is pretty "crashy" ;)

Comment: Not perfect since it only caters to AIR and AS3 apps.

Comment: Ha, ok. What, if anything in life, is perfect?

Comment: Wow.  I wish I had found this 2 years ago.  It just goes to show you that, as programmers, we are so used watching shell output fly by that we sometimes forget how nice a well engineered GUI debugger can be.

Answer (score 4):

Vizzy makes life easier if you want a basic logfile viewer. You just install the debug player and then install Vizzy.  It is a window that tails the flashlog file. The sweet thing is that is does all the mm.cfg file b.s. for you.

http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/

Comment: Easy to use tool. Once a debug flash player is installed, no configuration is needed. All done by Vizzy. Browser independent. Cool tool.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not as fancy as the others or cutting edge, but I used to create my own log function in the flash movie (funnily enough, called log) that called trace and also called a js function on the page (using whatever method your comfortable with). The function on the page was just a simple console.log() with Firebug. Simple and worked a treat.

Answer (score 2):

I am a happy [Thunderbolt](http://code.google.com/p/flash-thunderbolt/) user, maybe it is also worth a look (multiple log levels, plays nicely with firebug out of the box).

Answer (score 0):

Since macromedia was aquired by adobe,I thought it should be 'D :\Documents and Settings\user_name\Application Data\Adobe\Flash Player\Logs\flashlog.txt '.Which resutlted in loss of few  minutes for me.Finally i decide to give it a try to look at D:\Documents and Settings\user_name\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player\Logs\flashlog.txt and bingo i could see the flash trace() outputs.

I wonder why adobe is sill keeping the log file location in macromedia folder.Whatever it is I can see the trace ouptuts of flash applications run inside a browser and i am a happy man :)

Answer (score 0):

In windows, If you use a localized version (i.e. spanish) of the operating system, 'Application Data' must be replaced with the localized version (i.e. "Datos de programa")

Answer (score 0):

Unix's [`tail` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29) works well for me:

`tail -f ~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash\ Player/Logs/flashlog.txt`

The `-f` switch keeps the log open and tails it via stdout into an open Terminal window. This is a Mac solution, I'm not sure what the Windows `tail` equivalent is.

Note that path is based on [this document](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/configure-debugger-version-flash-player.html), posted above by @Jarvis.