# Flash 10 Debugger flashlog.txt

Tags: firefox-addon, trace, flash-cs3

I have installed the [Adobe Flash Player 10 debugger](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) for Firefox 3 and I am unable to locate the flashlog.txt file or use the debugger features online, other than to show redraw regions. I have installed the FireFox extension ["Flash Tracer"](http://www.sephiroth.it/firefox/flashtracer/) which in theory is compatible with my firefox version, and am now trying to make it work.

I cannot locate the flashlog.txt or the log directory under C:\Documents and Settings{user}\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player\ and I am sure I have installed the debugger properly. My mm.cfg file did not exist, and I created it manually. The Flash tracer plugin is unable to read a file from the location it should be in for an XP comp. Specifically, it says

> flashlog.txt file does't exists. Open settings dialog first.

What do I do? I REALLY need this addon to work properly. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at my [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864155/see-trace-of-flash-when-running-in-browser/864346#864346) for installing and configuring the Flash Tracer addon with Flash Debug Player 10.

Comment: I actually got it working, thanks anyway. I had to uninstall regular flash player first for some reason.