# Possible to turn on logging / debugging, or otherwise solve a streaming issue in Flash?

Tags: debugging, flash

I know virtually nothing about Flash so I'm kind of casting about in the dark.

I have the misfortune of being a BT customer, and whilst I have reasonable bandwidth (can view streaming high res video fine) I always have problems listening to radio programmes from the BBC. I think it could be buffering due to traffic shaping, or it could be the Flash applet used to play the content, or something else.

Is it possible to bring up some kind of debugging console, or view some kind of error log to see if there is some diagnostic information that could be useful in finding the problem?

Chrome/Firefox/Safari using Adobe Flash player 10.2.159 on Mac OS X 10.6

EDIT: In the debug Flash player the 'debug' option is greyed out, suggesting that the swf was compiled without debug symbols. This was created by a third party (BBC) not me.

Comment: Similar post on stack overflow - for output to browser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864155/see-trace-of-flash-when-running-in-browser

Comment: Simlar but not identical. I want any information at all, including but not limited to trace messages.

Answer (score 1):

You could install the debug Flash Player, so you should see if an error occurs (a popup will appear on the screen) during the streaming.[flash player debugger download](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html)

You should also disable flash player plugin and turn on debugger. If you're using Chrome type chrome://plugins the disable flash player and enable Adobe Shockwave for Director Netscape plug-in.